# Android Cast to a group

Tags: android, chromecast

My app has been supporting Chromecast for years, however it looks like casting to a GROUP doesn't work properly.
When  I do so, I can hear the connection to every Cast device in the group, but only one is actually playing the episode.
I'm not here to share my code, but just to know if there's something specific to do to cast to a Group.

BTW I'm using the latest Cast libraries

EDIT: It looks like it works fine when using playback speed 1.0x, but a different speed breaks Group casting. It looks like a Cast bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it works fine when using playback speed 1.0x, but a different speed breaks Group casting. It looks like a Cast bug